# How to clear the contents of a file with .bin extension

Tags: c#, .net

I need to clear the contents of a  particular file with .bin extension.

How do I do it?

Comment: Depends on your definition of "clear".

Comment: What do you mean for 'clear'. Write all zero in the file keeping the same size?

Comment: Have you tried the File operations in .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code `clears` the bin file passed in.
The meaning of 'clear' is defined as:

> Set every byte inside the passed file to zero and preserve the
>   existing file size

```
private void SetFileToZero(string inputFile)
{
    // Remove previous backup file
    string tempFile = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFile), "saved.bin");
    if(File.Exists(tempFile)) File.Delete(tempFile);

    // Get current length of input file (minus 4 byte)
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(inputFile);
    int pos = Convert.ToInt32(fi.Length) - 4;
    string name = fi.FullName;

    // Move the input file to "saved.bin"
    fi.MoveTo(tempFile);

    // Create a zero byte length file with the requested name
    using(FileStream st = File.Create(name))
    {
      // Position the file pointer at a position 4 byte less than the required size
      UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
      BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(st, utf8);
      bw.Seek(pos, SeekOrigin.Begin);

      // Write the last 4 bytes
      bw.Write(0);
    }
}
```

The OS honors the request to write at a certain position in a file, also if this position is beyond the actual length. To do this, the OS extends the file to the requested lenght and fill it with zeros. (This is really fast, delay barely noticeable)
N.B. For safety reason, I make a backup copy of the file and, after a MoveTo, don't use the information in the FileInfo var because it changes to refer to the moved file.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the file with zero size, you can do:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"particular.bin", String.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1):

It will delete all file with .bin extension recursively under D:\test directory.

```
if (Directory.Exists(@"D:\test"))
{
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\test", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
        if (fileInfo.Name.EndsWith(".bin"))
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `fileInfo.Name.EndsWith(".bin")` would work since the `.bin` is the extension of the file. Its not included in the file name.

Comment: It's also including your file name extension. File extension also include on file path at string[] files, so actually, you can avoid FileInfo instance and refer directly to file path like if (file.EndsWith(...

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ClearContents
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //get all the files which has the .bin extension in the specified directory
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("D:\\", "*.bin");

            foreach (string f in files)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(f, string.Empty); //clear the contents
            }
        }
    }
}
```